# how can I ask for user input and print in in mips assembly

Tags: assembly, input, mips

I started to earn on my own mips assembly and I want to ask for 2 inputs from the user and add them and print them to the screen.
help would be great!!

Comment: I/O depends on the execution environment, which you have not specified.

Comment: Write proper code, assemble and execute.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very good at mips but i'll try. What you want are keyboard controller registers. There are two registers involved. Ok so the keyboard controller  has two specific keyboard  registers one of which is the receiver data register. The two registers  are 'stored' (mapped to)  `0xFFFF0000` and `0xFFFF0004`. Looking up I/O registers might help.

Also to print the text to screen uses

```
li $v0, (some number, i forgot)
syscall
```

Again dont take my word for this stuff